# Firebase - serve error

Tags: firebase

I started the Firebase FriendlyChat tutorial, and it worked until I decided to stop the `firebase serve` process, and started it again and stoped it, and then when I started it with `firebase serve` again it said the port was already in use.

So I stopped a few processes with `kill -QUIT <PID>` and when I tried to start it gave me this error:

```
[debug] Command:      /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase serve
[debug] CLI Version:  3.0.0
[debug] Platform:     darwin
[debug] Node Version: v5.9.1
[debug] Time:         Thu May 19 2016 00:03:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[debug] ---------------------------------------------------------------    
[debug] 
[info] Starting Firebase development server...
[info] 
[info] Project Directory: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/firebase/chat/web-start
[warn] ⚠  Port 5000 is not available. Trying another port...
[warn] ⚠  Port 5001 is not available. Trying another port...
[debug] TypeError: Cannot read property 'public' of undefined
at Server.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/commands/serve.js:24:15)
at Server.g (events.js:273:16)
at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
at Server.emit (events.js:179:7)
at emitListeningNT (net.js:1260:10)
at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:380:13)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:407:11)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

So I restarted my mac and tried it again without success.
Then I decided to reinstall the firebase and firebase-tool package. But that didn't work.

So can anyone help me, or did someone had this problem too?

Thanks in advance.

Theo

Comment: Just had a chat with someone more familiar with the tool - can you check your firebase.json file has a 'public' key in there? That should have the directory where files are served from as a value.

Comment: Hello, the firebase.json is filled with only {} , even after I ran firebase use --add

Comment: Does firebase init work?

Comment: It works now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fix for why port 5000 is taken unfortunately, but as a workaround you can do:

```
firebase serve -p 5001
```

To serve on another port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating Node to 6.2.0 or downgrading to stable 4.4.4?

https://nodejs.org/en/